# Convert from List of preparedStatements to PreparedStatement batch

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I have an arrayList of PreparedStatement

```
ArrayList<PreparedStatement> prestmtBatchList = new ArrayList<PreparedStatement>();
```

With time I add a number of preparedStatements in it:

```
PreparedStatement ps = DBUtility.returnInsertQueryAsString("ind_it_decl_sec10log", keysToSaveInLog, itdeclsec10loginfo, con);
                                    if(!ErmUtil.isNull(ps)){
                                        prestmtBatchList.add(ps);
                                    }
```

I want to execute them at once, hence need to be converted in Batch. I know it sounds silly to do this.

Comment: tell me why you need to have ArrayList of PreparedStatement? You can use single PreparedStatement and add them in the batch and execute the batch, that will be meaningful i guess

Answer (score 0):

Still you want PreparedStatement , place the logic of the function in your PreparedStatement code itself.The below solution will help you.

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

PreparedStatement ps = //instantiate
pstmt.setInt( 1, 1243);
pstmt.setString( 2, "test" );
pstmt.setString( 3, "test" );
pstmt.setInt( 4, 123 );

ps.addBatch();

pstmt.setInt( 1, 1243);
pstmt.setString( 2, "12334" );
pstmt.setString( 3, "21423" );
pstmt.setInt( 4, 123 );

ps.addBatch();

int[] count = ps.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
```

Comment: Won't the second ps , will overwrite the content of first one?

Comment: This doesn't answer my Question, mate :)

Answer (score 0):

For batch execution, you can use Prepared statement's native executeBatch() method.
To improve performance of Java database application is running queries with setAutoCommit(false). By default new JDBC connection has there auto commit mode ON, which means every individual SQL Statement will be executed in its own transaction. while without auto commit you can group SQL statement into logical transaction, which can either be committed or rolled back by calling commit() or rollback().

Below code explains further :-

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test1");
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 102);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test2");
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 103);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test3");
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            dbConnection.commit();
```

Comment: from where did you copy this, it's always better to provide reference along.

Answer (score 0):

instead doubting one's help better suggest solutions. Anyways enjoy the whole class.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

/**
 *
 * @author vaibhav.kashyap
 */


import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class PreparedBatchJDBC {

    private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb";
    private static final String DB_USER = "root";
    private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        try {

            batchInsertRecordsIntoTable();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

    }

    private static void batchInsertRecordsIntoTable() throws SQLException {

        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

        String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
                + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            dbConnection.setAutoCommit(false);

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 101);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test1");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 102);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test2");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 103);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "test3");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());
            preparedStatement.addBatch();

            preparedStatement.executeBatch();

            dbConnection.commit();

            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            dbConnection.rollback();

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (dbConnection != null) {
                dbConnection.close();
            }

        }

    }

    private static Connection getDBConnection() {

        Connection dbConnection = null;

        try {

            Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        try {

            dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                              DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            return dbConnection;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        return dbConnection;

    }

    private static java.sql.Timestamp getCurrentTimeStamp() {

        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        return new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());

    }

}
```

Hope this would help too.